# How to add an url field to a serializer with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am following the tutorial on [Django Rest Framework - Tutorial 3 Class based views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/).

**How to add an url field (pointing to the current snippet) to a serializer?**

**serializers.py**

```python
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
```

**urls.py**

```python
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.SnippetList.as_view()),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SnippetDetail.as_view()),
]
```

**Actual output**

```json
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "title":"",
      "code":"foo = \"bar\"\n",
      "linenos":false,
      "language":"python",
      "style":"friendly"
   }
]
```

**Desired output**

```
[  
       {  
          "id":1,
          "url":"http://192.168.28.131:8000/snippets/1/",
          "title":"",
          "code":"foo = \"bar\"\n",
          "linenos":false,
          "language":"python",
          "style":"friendly"
       },

    ]
```

Comment: As long as you follow the naming convention or have named urls: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` serializer and `HyperlinkedIdentityField` field

From [Django Rest Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer)

> The `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` class is similar to the
>   ModelSerializer class except that it uses hyperlinks to represent
>   relationships, rather than primary keys. The url field will be
>   represented using a `HyperlinkedIdentityField` serializer field, and
>   any relationships on the model will be represented using a
>   `HyperlinkedRelatedField` serializer field.

E.g (with your case) :

```python
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippet-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
```

Of course, `view_name` value must match the name of an url declared in `urls.py` (or not elsewhere) used to get all information about a snippet.

E.g :

```python
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.SnippetDetail.as_view(), name='snippet-detail'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks! My `urls.py` looks somewhat different. It uses `views.SnippetDetail.as_view()` (copy pasted from tutorial). When I use your definition I get `__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)` any thoughts?

Comment: yeah, just add  a `name` value. I updated my example. It doesn't works because you use Class based view. Use this : `url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.SnippetDetail.as_view(), name='snippet-detail')`

Answer (score 0):

When using a viewset, specify complete reverse url name as `view_name`

```
class XyzSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='app1:api:xyz-detail',
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Xyz
        fields = ( 'id', 'url')
```